# Is there a way to customize Android's Google Map Location Picker Intent?(Just like whatsapp)?

Tags: android, google-maps

Entire app is built with material design and app toolbar bar color is green and toolbar text color is white in all the screens. But in Android's built in location picker intent toolbar is appearing in the green color but toolbar text is appearing in black color. Black color is used no where in my app colors.xml file

Right now I included default placepicker (like shown in below link)
https://developers.google.com/places/android/placepicker

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom colors in your application using the [material theme](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html).

> The place picker inherits the colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark
>   attributes from the theme. This is useful for maintaining a consistent
>   brand across your app and the place picker.

Comment: Yes as you said it is taking colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark from theme. But toolbar text-color is appearing in black color but in every other screen toolbar-text color is white only.
below xml is my value.xml
 <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>